# Another application instead of JShint?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jshint

JShint cannot be used for VS 2013.
I'm looking for a tool that is similiar as jshint for VS 2013.

Do you know anything that you can recommend me to use?

Answer (score 0):

JsHint can be integrated with Visual Studio using the [WebEssentials tools](http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript).

[image]

It's also relatively simple to [integrate JsHint into MsBuild](https://nemetht.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/integrate-jslintjshint-into-the-msbuild-the-easy-way/).

Comment: If I understand, you have used webessentials tools before? If yes, what is you reflection about it?

Comment: I would not do Web Development in Visual Studio without it.